# How to remove the single cart item using codeigniter cart class?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, shopping-cart, cart

I am using codeigniter cart class for my shopping cart project. I have number of items on the cart. Now I do have cart row id. Now what exactly i need to do is, need to remove the particular item from the cart not all the contents(Destroying cart).

```
$cartcontents = $this->cart->product_options($rowid);
```

and unseting all contents. but doesn't works out. Please do help you anybody have an idea. Thank You.

Answer (score 12):

```
$data = array(
'rowid'   => '30ef30b64204a3088a26bc2e6ecf7602',
'qty'     => 0
);

$this->cart->update($data);
```

use this

Answer (score 0):

Use "removeCartItem" function in your controller to do this...

```
function removeCartItem($rowid) {   
        $data = array(
            'rowid'   => $rowid,
            'qty'     => 0
        );

        $this->cart->update($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a remove button at view page and add row id with link. After that create a function and pass row id and put quantity 0 and pass that array in update function.

```
public function remove_cart_product($data) {
  $row_id=$data;
  $qty=0;
  $array=array('rowid' =>$row_id ,'qty'=>$qty );
  $this->cart->update($array);
  print_r($this->cart->contents());exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the quantity is set to zero, the item will be removed from the cart.

```
$data = array(
           'rowid' => 'b99ccdf16028f015540f341130b6d8ec',
           'qty'   => 0
        );

$this->cart->update($data);
```

Here, set QTY = 0 then it will be removed.