# Codeigniter - unset session data (inside user_data array)

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, session

So I have a 'cart' array inside my session like this

```
Array
(
[session_id] => 4a5a5dca22728fb0a84364eeb405b601
[ip_address] => 127.0.0.1
[user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7;
[last_activity] => 1303142623
[cart] => Array( [1]=1;
                 [2]=3;
                )
)
```

My question, I want to unset one of the id inside cart array..but not the whole 'cart' data

```
$this->session->unset_userdata($id); //$id as in [cart][$id]
//or even like this below
$tmp = $this->session->userdata('cart');          
$this->session->unset_userdata($tmp[$pid]);
```

I tried the above, but it doesn't do a thing. Help!

PS: I pass the $id through uri and can echo the $id just fine

====================================================
update:
Thank you for your replies, but I somehow resolved my problem. I did it like this

```
$tmp = $this->session->userdata('cart');          
unset($tmp[$pid]);
$this->session->set_userdata('cart',$tmp);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561332/how-to-remove-the-single-cart-item-using-codeigniter-cart-class

Comment: @sbaaaang: I am not using CI built-in shopping cart class

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
$tmp = $this->session->userdata('cart');
unset($tmp[$id]);
$this->session->set_userdata('cart', $tmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unset as

```
$tmp = $this->session->userdata('cart');          
unset($tmp[$pid]);
$this->session->set_userdata(array("cart"=>$tmp));
```